# Нужно ли двоеточие перед перечислением после слов "в числе которых"?

Tags: пунктуация

Мероприятия, в числе которых: выставки, театральные постановки, концерты, длятся на протяжении 8 дней.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не нужно.

Двоеточие при перечислении тут не подходит:
1) обобщающее слово отсутствует;
2) после двоеточия не подставляется "а именно";
3) пауза полностью отсутствует за счёт придаточного предложения, которое находится внутри главного;
4) три элемента — это не много.